# Background css property is not coming only in IE8

Tags: html, css

I have the below css class and i am using it in my html code.

```
.status-mob {
    background: url(/img/status.png) -55px -6px no-repeat;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    width: 20px;
}
```

The above css is working fine in Firefox and Chrome. But not working in IE8

In IE8, When i inspect the html element the first property(background) is not coming only in IE8.

Somehow reason the "background" property is not coming in IE8. Has anyone ever faced issue like this?

Can you anyone tell me what could be the reason?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you should put path of img in quotes: `url("/img/status.png")`? IE is strange in every way you can think...

Comment: Use `background-image` and add yuotes to your path

Comment: tried with quotes. Still background property is not coming in IE8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
.status-mob {
background: url('../img/status.png') -55px -6px no-repeat;
height: 20px;
margin-top: -1px;
width: 20px;
}
```

or you can try writing them separately

```
background-image: url('../img/status.png');
background-size:-55px -6px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 2):

remove the `/` from /img/status.png and that will resolve your issue.

For instance,

`background: url(img/status.png) -55px -6px no-repeat;`

***PS:** if the image is one level up, use `../`*

Comment: True, but quotes does not make a big impact which `/` makes. - @C-Link

Comment: Thx @C-Link, I do remember testing with or without quotes, but eventually the path makes the things to create weird behavior especially the starting slash `/`

Comment: Then if it is in your parent directory, try with `../` and also with `./` -@ezhil

Answer (score 0):

Is the image bigger than 55x6 pixels? You are placing it 55 pixels left and 6 pixels up from the corner of the element, so it needs to be bigger than that to show up.

Also, is the image really stored in the "img" folder under the root of the website? You might need a relative path like "img/status.png" or "../img/status.png" instead of the absolute path "/img/status.png".